# Excepción no especificada en Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Lo que pasa es que aunque el proyecto no marca ningún error a la hora de correrlo manda un mensaje de alerta en la pestaña de notificaciones que dice

> Unexpected Exception component must be showing in the screen to determine its location

y tras un rato de ver que error podría tener el código encontre que cuando elimino el siguiente trozo deja de lanzar el error.

`

```
NodoSimple<T> temp = aux.getSalas().getCabeza();

//El while se encarga de llenar las salas con peliculas por defecto

    while(temp != null){

        if(temp.getDato() instanceof Sala2D){
            ((Sala2D)temp.getDato()).agregarPelicula(new Pelicula("","","",5,((Sala2D)temp.getDato())));
        }else if(temp.getDato() instanceof Sala3D){
            ((Sala3D)temp.getDato()).agregarPelicula(new Pelicula("","","",5,((Sala3D)temp.getDato())));
        }else if(temp.getDato() instanceof Sala4DX){
            ((Sala4DX)temp.getDato()).agregarPelicula(new Pelicula("","","",5,((Sala4DX)temp.getDato())));
        }

        temp = temp.getProximo();

    }`
```

Quisiera saber que recomiendan, si hay alguna forma de arreglarlo sin tener que eliminar el casting o si tengo que replantear la forma en la que estoy haciéndolo y usar algo distinto al casting

Comment: La excepción si que esta especificada, te dice que para saber la posición el elemento debe estar mostrándose en pantalla. Ademas diría que ahí no esta el problema, ¿que linea es en la que salta la excepción y que contiene esa linea?

Comment: no te sale el número de línea en la excepción?